# Some questions about series and generalized integrals

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, power-series

Do someone of you know any good site about generalized integrals and series (convergence and divergence) with example exercises with detailed solutions ?

I would be happy if you did know any. My compendium about series, generalized integrals and power series is not enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For harder competitive problems, try T. Andreescu's Putnam and Beyond. For more theoretical problems try Rudin's Principles of mathematical analysis. Another good relatively new book is T.Tao's Analysis I (Volumes 1 and 2).